# How to input plot from matplotlib into pdf using reportlab?

Tags: python, pdf, reportlab

I'm using an online program with python scripting capabilities in the background - so there are limitations on what I can do.

I am trying to take a plot that is plotted based on a dataframe and input that plot into a pdf using reportlab. After that report is generated, it needs to output a clickable link to download the pdf.

The following code inputs the table but not the plot and I can't figure out why - I've been working on this code for 3 days and I'm going insane.

```
from io import BytesIO
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Image
import base64
from IPython.display import HTML, display

# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # 

# create a sample dataframe
data = {'Name': ['John', 'Jane', 'Bob'], 'Age': [30, 25, 40], 'Gender': ['M', 'F', 'M']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #


# create a buffer to hold the generated PDF
buffer = BytesIO()

# create a PDF object
pdf_name = "Trendminer.pdf"
pdf = SimpleDocTemplate(buffer, pagesize=letter)

# create a table from the dataframe
table_data = [df.columns.tolist()] + df.values.tolist()
table = Table(table_data)

# Create a Matplotlib figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.plot(df['Name'])

# Save the figure to a PDF file
plt.savefig(pdf_name)

# add the table to the PDF
pdf.build([table])
pdf.build([fig])

# reset the buffer position to the beginning
buffer.seek(0)

# encode the PDF in base64 for download
b64 = base64.b64encode(buffer.getvalue()).decode()

# create a link to download the PDF file
link = '<a href="data:application/pdf;base64,{0}" download="dataframe.pdf">Right-click -> Save As to Download PDF</a>'.format(b64)

# display the link
display(HTML(link))
```

Comment: There is a lot of missing context in your code. For example where does the `display()` or `HTML()` functions comes from? Can you provide a [example]?

Comment: I've added the imports for you.

Comment: Updated the code - I got some of it to work. It now generates a pdf with the table from the dataframe but I still can't get it to input the plot.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that I grasp what your intentions are. So I will suppose that your want:

- To create a PDF document from the content of a Pandas' DataFrame

  - On the first page, you want a table with the data
  - On the second page you want a plot of the values of the data
- To save the file locally under the name "Trendminer.pdf"
- To run this script in a Jupyter Notebook to create a link to download

Then I think you do not need Reportlab. You can use the PDF exporting capacities of `matplotlib` to do all this:

```py
import io

import pandas as pd

from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import base64
from IPython.display import HTML, display

data_index = ['John', 'Jane', 'Bob']
data = {'Age': [30, 25, 40], 'Gender': ['M', 'F', 'M']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=data_index)
df.index.name = 'Name'

table_data = [[row_index] + [str(row_element) for row_element in row.values] for (row_index, row) in df.iterrows()]
table_headers = [df.index.name] + list(df.columns)

# create a buffer to hold the generated PDF
file_in_memory = io.BytesIO()

with PdfPages(file_in_memory) as booklet:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    fig.set_size_inches(11, 8.5)

    table = ax.table(cellText=table_data, colLabels=table_headers, loc='center', cellLoc='center')
    ax.axis('off')

    booklet.savefig()

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    fig.set_size_inches(11, 8.5)    
    
    ax.plot(df['Age'], label='Age')
    ax.legend()

    ax2 = ax.twinx()
    ax2.plot(df['Gender'], label='Gender', color='orange')
    ax2.legend()
    
    booklet.savefig()

with open("Trendminer.pdf", "wb") as output_file:
    output_file.write(file_in_memory.getvalue())

# encode the PDF in base64 for download
encoded_file = base64.b64encode(file_in_memory.getvalue()).decode()

# create a link to download the PDF file
link = '<a href="data:application/pdf;base64,{0}" download="dataframe.pdf">Right-click -> Save As to Download PDF</a>'.format(encoded_file)

# display the link
display(HTML(link))
```

To understand this solution, you will need to read on:

- [Displaying a table of data in matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.table.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.table)
- [How to create multi-page PDF](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/misc/multipage_pdf.html)